# ListView updating Items without being recreated

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I want my ListView to work something like the following:
When I press a button (probably from context-menu), I want the user to be able to select more then one item from ListView (probably using check-boxes), but those check-boxes should not be visible before that.
So, the point is, after the user presses a button (let's say "Delete more items"), the listview, should update itself, and appear on every row of the list, a checkbox should appear (allowing me to select the items ID to pass those to server).

How can I achieve that, without having to recreate the list from zero? (how to setVisibility ON, keeping the other content of the ListView as it is, and not doing another request to server).

PS. If you guys, have another better idea, on achieving the Delete More Items, would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an idea, haven't tried it myself: you build in a checkbox in your listitem layout. Normally, in the getView of your adapter, you set it invisible with
checkBox.setVisibility(8);

When you want to show them, you set some boolean

```
showBoxes
```

of your adapter to true, then in the getView oyu don't hide the checkboxes. 
Then

```
notifyDataSetChanged
```

on the adapter.

Hope it's clear what I mean.